# Firebase Authentication Failure because of Gradle?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

My project seems fine, but still does not work. Am I supposed to use highest version of dependencies? Is that it? For example `firebase-auth:11.2.2` instead of 10.0.1 which I used?

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Which error you got ?

Comment: Yes, and also you have to make sure your  `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are mixing the old dependencies with the new once. So in order to solve your problem, you need to remove all the dependencies that are old and use the latest version of the new once.

Remove this lines of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
```

and add **only** this lines:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
```